# Regex replacement using sed and awk

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to replace first, second and third `%f` with `a b  and c` respectively using `sed and awk`.

```
(51.7296373326*%f)+(41.7319764456*%f)+(-193.993966414*%f)
```

This is what i've tried

```
sed "s|(51.7296373326*%f)|(51.7296373326*a)|g" dump1.txt
```

The values are not constant..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant `sed` **or** `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{a[++i]="a";a[++i]="b";a[++i]="c"}
     {for(x=1;x<=i;x++)sub(/%f/,a[x])}7' file
```

if the replacement list is big, like `a-z`, you can put them in a file, first load it into array `a` instead of loading them in `BEGIN` block.

Note, the codes could be optimized by checking the return value of `sub`, if 0, break.

Comment: Does the job. Thanks! I'll mark it when the timer is out.

Comment: But it doesn't write to a file. like `sed -i`

Comment: @pistal `awk '...code...' input > output` if you want to `in-place` saving and awk version < 4. you could `awk 'codes' input > output && mv output input`

Comment: which version your gnu-awk is?

Comment: @pistal `>=4.1.0` has `inplace` extension. you don't have it. just do `awk.. && mv`